# Extracting type T from Option<T>

Tags: rust

I have some code generated by bindgen that has function pointers represented by `Option<T>`.

```
pub type SomeFnPointerType = ::std::option::Option<
  unsafe extern "C" fn ( /* .. large number of argument types .. */) 
    -> /* return type */
> ;
```

I want to store the unwrapped values in a structure. However, there are no type aliases for the inner function pointer types, so how can I define that structure? I cannot refactor the code because it's automatically generated.

I want to do something like this (in C++'ish pseudo code):

```
struct FunctionTable {
  decltype((None as SomeFnPointerType).unwrap()) unwrappedFn;
  /* ... */
};
```

or maybe just `SomeFnPointerType::T` if that is allowed.

Is it possible to achieve that in Rust? If not, the only way I see it is to manually define those types by copy-pasting code from the generated file into a separate handwritten file and keep the types in sync manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a trait that exposes the `T` as an associated type.

```
trait OptionExt {
    type Type;
}

impl<T> OptionExt for Option<T> {
    type Type = T;
}

type MyOption = Option<fn()>;

fn foo(f: <MyOption as OptionExt>::Type) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    foo(|| {});
}
```